# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass-rails"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, bundler

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I have this error when I run bundle install for a new project. I am using Rails 4.2.3 on Mac OSx Yosemite

```
In Gemfile:
compass-rails (~> 2.0.4) ruby depends on
  sass-rails (<= 5.0.1) ruby

sass-rails (5.0.3)
```

Any idea on why I got this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to add version of `sass-rails` gem to your Gemfile. Find a string:

```
gem "sass-rails"
```

And replace it to the

```
gem "sass-rails", "5.0.1"
```

This error occured because of little old version of `compass-rails` gem. You can review [line of gemspec](https://github.com/Compass/compass-rails/blob/master/compass-rails.gemspec#L21) to see that's newer version of `compass-rails` wouldn't raise exception (because of `sass-rails 5.0.3` is lower than `5.1`)

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
```

or

```
source :github
```

at the top of your GemFile

Comment: Sorry I was thinking about wrong error. Lower sass-rails version to 5.0.1. It seems compass dependency was not yet updated.

Comment: I lowered the sass-rails version to 5.0.1 and updated the gems with bundle update ... now I able to run the web app. Thank you!